Programmatically pasting works in Xcode debug but not in TestFlight
I have a Macos app I am developing where I created a button that programmatically pastes the user's clipboard to wherever their selection is. This behavior works fine in Xcode local debugging but doesn't paste at all when in TestFlight.
Also is there an easier way to have a closer to 'real-life' scenario when debugging locally to avoid the discrepancy between TestFlight and building locally?
 func pasteText() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let source = CGEventSource(stateID: .combinedSessionState)

        let vDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(9), keyDown: true)
        vDown?.flags = .maskCommand  // Add Command modifier

        let vUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(9), keyDown: false)

        vDown?.post(tap: .cgAnnotatedSessionEventTap)
        vUp?.post(tap: .cgAnnotatedSessionEventTap)
    }}


The reason this fails for TestFlight build is probably that you are sandboxed. Your app needs a user permission in the Privacy settings to control the computer.

Also is there an easier way to have a closer to 'real-life' scenario when debugging locally to avoid the discrepancy between TestFlight and building locally?

Choose Product > Archive and export from the archive.

Oh yeah I was sandboxed and had to add that permission in the privacy setting when debugging locally, but shouldn't I also be able to add that privacy setting in TestFlight?

I ended up fixing this issue by playing around with the privacy and security settings for the app. It seems like even though I gave accessibility permissions for the app while running the app locally, I had to delete the permissions and add them again for TestFlight even though the permission still appeared to be granted.

How is that different from my answer?

@matt It's basically the same it's just that the accessibility and privacy settings seem to be buggy when switching from Xcode environment to TestFlight. Even if the permission was granted earlier while debugging in Xcode, the privacy settings need to be turned off and back on again when running the app through TestFlight, at least in my case.
